# Iterate a list in reverse order and create dynamic dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to create a big dict that encapsulate dicts from a list of keys: 
i have this following list :

```
lis = ['model', 'properties', 'config', 'properties', 'zookeeperStorageSize', 'default']
```

i can iterate in reverse order this list but i'm not able to create this big object

here the output that  i want :

```
  {'model': {'properties': {'config': {'properties': {'zookeeperStorageSize': {'default': '50m'}}}}}}
```

any leads ?

Answer (score 2):

here is my solution:

```
def listtodict(mylist, final_value):
    if len(mylist) == 1:
        return {mylist[0]:final_value}
    else:
        return {mylist[0]:listtodict(mylist[1:], final_value)}

mylist = ['model', 'properties', 'config', 'properties', 'zookeeperStorageSize', 'default']
print(listtodict(mylist, "50m"))
```

prints:

```
{'model': {'properties': {'config': {'properties': {'zookeeperStorageSize': {'default': '50m'}}}}}}
```

Comment: many thanks @Ali Yılmaz , i have another problem, how to avoid for example if we have another list where we have some same key : ['model', 'properties', 'resources', 'properties', 'cpu', 'default'] it's not the exact list and it will overwrite, how to update encapsulate dict in this case ?

Comment: @MelDev so, in this case, you want to have a `list` of dictionaries for `properties`'s value, right? those two dictionaries have single keys, named `zookeeperStorageSize` and `cpu` respectively.

Comment: @MelDev or do you want to override current dictionary and `update` it with the new values?

Comment: i want to update the dict with the existing key not to override it, for instance here i have to update the sub dict properties by adding the listtodict['resources', 'properties', 'cpu', 'default']

Comment: So whenever we have the same keys in order it should update the appropriate key by adding the new object @Ali Yılmaz

Comment: can you elaborate what you mean by '*whenever we have the same keys in order*'? because *keys* are what you try to change/override. Do you mean "the length of list is same as before", or "first 2 keys are the same as before"?

Comment: we have key and dict as value of those key, i want whenever we have the same key in all sub dict to merge the new dict with the existing one not to override with the new object @ Ali Yılmaz

Comment: 1- dict1 = listtodict(['model', 'properties', 'config', 'properties', 'zookeeperStorageSize', 'default']) 2-['model', 'properties', 'resources', 'properties', 'cpu', 'default']  we have here the two first keys are equal so i want now to add listtodict(['resources', 'properties', 'cpu', 'default']) to the sub dict dict1[model][properties]

Comment: actually i want a  generic way of updating my dictionary without overwriting the subdictionaries

Comment: @MelDev I understand. So then, in this case, resulting dictionary's Key=properties will have two dicts, right? In other words, we can keep a list of dicts for each key, so that whenever another list is added to that KEY, we can append the corresponding dictionary to this KEYs value. Is this what you intend to do? If not, I would like you to explain *merging* two dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

This is a functional solution using `collections.defaultdict` to create a nested defaultdict of defaultdicts:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import reduce
from operator import getitem

tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)
d = tree()

def getFromDict(dataDict, mapList):
    """Iterate nested dictionary"""
    return reduce(getitem, mapList, dataDict)

lis = ['model', 'properties', 'config', 'properties', 'zookeeperStorageSize', 'default']

getFromDict(d, lis[:-1])[lis[-1]] = '50m'

print(d['model']['properties']['config']['properties']['zookeeperStorageSize']['default'])
# 50
```

Answer (score 0):

- [reversed](http://%20%20%20%20https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) function returns a reverse iterator.

**Ex.**

```
mylist = ['model', 'properties', 'config', 'properties',    'zookeeperStorageSize', 'default']

output_dict = {}
for key in reversed(mylist):
  if mylist.index(key) == len(mylist)-1:
     output_dict = {key: '50m'}
  else:
     # re-assign output_dict value
     output_dict = {key: output_dict}
print output_dict
```

**O/P:**

```
{'model': {'properties': {'config': {'properties':{'zookeeperStorageSize': {'default': '50mb'}}}}}}
```